# jquery button works fine first time but second time not working

Tags: html

I created a very simple index.html file and inside I included some jquery script. You can see below:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var $tweets = $('.tweets');
        var current_position = -1;
        function getTweets(){
          var index = streams.home.length - 1;
          var cp = index;
          while(index >= current_position + 1){
            var tweet = streams.home[index];
            $tweets.append('<div class="twe"><span class="name" style="color:blue">' + '@' + tweet.user + ': ' + ' </span><span class="message">' + tweet.message + tweet.created_at + '</span></div>');
            index--;
          }
          current_position = cp;
        }
        getTweets();
        $('button').click(function(){
          getTweets();
        });
        $('.name').click(function(){
          $tweets.prepend('<div>' + 'objname' + streams.home.length + '</div>');          
        });

      });
</script>
```

there is one button used for updates all the tweets and dynamically put them  in the section with class="tweets" part. And this button works fine no matter how many times I press it.

Then I add click event to all those with class name 'name' and once I click it , it will add 'objname' + streams.home.length to the front of my 
section class="tweets" part. The problem is first time , I CLICK the $('.name') it works fine , but later after I added more items through $('button') click event. it seems the new created $('.name') items is not clickable which means they don't generate 'objname' + streams.home.length to the front of my 
section with class="tweets" part. I am really confused here and don't know why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following

```
$("body").on("click",".name",function(){
          $tweets.prepend('<div>' + 'objname' + streams.home.length + '</div>');          
        });
```

As your element gets added runtime on the page, it needed to be taken care separately with help of "on" which bind events automatically when event gets created.

[check reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: thank you so much. It works and I never know it was caused by dynamic binding problem.